# How to clear an fd's input buffer?

Tags: c, file-descriptor

Reading an input is easy with

```
ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
```

However, if I don't need the contents at all, what is the effective and elegant way to decline it?

Background: I'm registered for an fd which becomes readable only when a specific condition happens. But I need to read the buffer (clear it actually) to be able to get the next event as well.

I could simply define a `buffer` and read the input into it, but if I (really) don't need the contents, how shall I call `read`, or do I have any other more suitable command for this?

Comment: That's an odd requirement. You want to clear until what condition? Not my DV btw.

Comment: Not that easy... A file descriptor is a stream and is generally buffered at the driver level. I know no simple way to clean it except reading its content. You cannot be sure at what moment what you are reading was written.

Comment: I want to clear everything what read would read.

Comment: @Daniel I'm afraid then you need to read until EOF.

Comment: Seems like the only side effect you want is to move the file pointer forward. Why not seek forward instead?

Comment: @JeffHolt: most non file fd are not seekable...

Comment: There might be a way if the device supports an ioctl call to clear unread input.

Comment: You can call reopen which will close and open the stream on the same filehandle.

Comment: Mr Occam says: don't multiply entities beyond necessity. `read` does what you need when you look at the data, and  `read` also does what you need when you don't look at the data. The only difference is you looking or not looking, `read` need not change.

Comment: What is "_the next event_"? Again that the fd has data readable? Why do you want this? And how do you know that this stream is at the right position? Depending on the underlying layer you cannot know how much is available, perhaps the data of the second "event" is already available.

Comment: *next event* is when fd become readable *again*.